# How To Sort Through An array from type "NameOfClass"

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, class

I have a Program that finds The Maximum distance between a pair of Points:
This is class Point:

```
public class Point {

  private int x;
  private  int y;
  public Point (int a, int b) {
      x=a; y=b;
  }
  public double distance (Point p){
    int tempx , tempy;
    tempx=(x-p.x)*(x-p.x);
    tempy=(y-p.y)*(y-p.y);
    return  Math.sqrt(tempx+tempy);
  }
  public void show(){
      System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
  }
}
```

And This is The Main Program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Point[] allPoints=new Point[5];
      int k=0;
      int rx,ry;
      while (k<=allPoints.length-1){             
      rx=(int)(1+Math.random()*10);               
      ry=(int)(1+Math.random()*10);
      allPoints[k]=new Point(rx, ry);
      k++;
      }

      int i,j,mi,mj;
      double mDis=0,cDis;
      mi=mj=0;
      i=0;
      while ( i<allPoints.length-1) {
        j=i+1;
        while (j<allPoints.length) {
          cDis= allPoints[i].distance(allPoints[j]);
          if (cDis>mDis){
          mDis=cDis; 
          mj=j; 
          mi=i;}
          j++;
         }    
         i++;
        }

      allPoints[mj].show();
      allPoints[mi].show();
        System.out.print("max dis is " + mDis +" first point: " + mi + " second point: " + mj);
} 
      //////////


}
```

As You Can see the program has an array with 5 "Cells" and it finds the pair with the Maximum distance, I wanted to know how I could change the program so that it would sort and print the points according to the distance between them.
for Example: Point1: 2,2 Point2: 6,6 Point3: 1,1
So The distance between Point3 and Point 1 is the smallest so The program should output: 1,1 2,2 6,6
the reason why 6,6 would be last because the distance between 6,6 and 2,2 is the greatest, Im new in Java so it would be a great help if you could explain it to me.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you clarify it more. What does "distance between each other" mean? Do you mean that you want to calculate maximum distance from all the points and then sort the results?

Comment: yes exactly, what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new Line object that consumes a pair of points. Put all combinations of points into a list of lines and sort that list based on the length of these lines (the distance between their points).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    while (i < allPoints.length - 1) {
        ...
        while (j < allPoints.length) {
            lines.add(new Line(allPoints[i], allPoints[j]));
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    Collections.sort(lines, Comparator.comparingDouble(Line::getLength));
    System.out.println("Lines: ");
    for (Line line : lines) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}

class Point {
    private int x;
    private  int y;

    public Point (int a, int b) {
        x=a; y=b;
    }

    public double distance (Point p){
        int tempx , tempy;
        tempx=(x-p.x)*(x-p.x);
        tempy=(y-p.y)*(y-p.y);
        return  Math.sqrt(tempx+tempy);
    }

    public void show(){
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "," + y + ")";
    }
}

class Line {
    private final Point a;
    private final Point b;
    private double length;

    public Line(Point a, Point b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.length = a.distance(b);
    }

    public double getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Line{" +
                "a=" + a +
                ", b=" + b +
                ", length=" + length +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with out adding methods and only using loops in the class of program?

Comment: @MicaelIllos why do you want to do so? The more you put into one method/class the harder it becomes to read.